# Use regex to extract substring from pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have columns with values like this:

```
Col1

1/1/100 'BA1
1/1/102Packe
1/1/102 'to_
```

And need to extract just 1/1/100 (from the first row) and so on (1/1/102...)

I am using:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.extract('(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)', expand=True)
```

But I'm getting only 1.

Not sure why this is not working, is there a problem with regex or I need some kind of mapping?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to only use a single capturing group:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.extract('(\d+/\d+/\d+)', expand=True)
                                     ^           ^
```

The `str.extract` method returns the value captured with the first capturing group, and your regex captures the first `1` into that group.

Test:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["1/1/100 'BA1", "1/1/102Packe", "1/1/102 'to_"]})
>>> df['col1'].str.extract('(\d+/\d+/\d+)', expand=True)
         0
0  1/1/100
1  1/1/102
2  1/1/102
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this also,

```
df['Col1']=df['Col1'].str.replace('\d+|/','')
```

**Note:** Regex is more powerful than `.str.replace`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this Regex:

```
df['col1'].str.extract('\b(\d/?)+', expand=True)
```